How To Deploy Angular SSR App To GCP App Engine Standard Without Pulling In Tons Of Files?
So Im not sure if this has been asked and answered but I've been trying to track this down for quite a while. It seems as though every time I try to deploy an angular app to app engine standard the build size is like 500+ MB on the app engine instance. I am using a .gcloudignore that is ignoring node_modules. I have also tried ignoring the src directory but it seems like app engine is trying to use that for some reason to build even though I have already built the dist folder in Cloud Build.
So here are all my files that matter:
app.yaml
service: my-app
runtime: nodejs20
env: standard
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
  - url: /
    static_dir: dist

.gcloudignore
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore
cypress/
e2e/

# Node.js dependencies:
node_modules/

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-purple/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.scss",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": []
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": []
            },
            "local": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "options": {
            "port": 4201
          },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:local"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "local"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {
            "prerender": false,
            "ssr": false,
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
            "firebaseProject": "my-app",
            "firebaseHostingSite": "my-app"
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": []
            },
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [],
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true
            },
            "local": {
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "cypress-run": {
          "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-open": {
          "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          }
        },
        "ct": {
          "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false,
            "testingType": "component"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:development"
            }
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@schematics/angular",
      "@cypress/schematic"
    ]
  }
}

cloudbuild.yaml
timeout: 1200s
steps:
  - name: 'node:20.7.0'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install']

  - name: 'node:20.7.0'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install', '-g', '@angular/cli']

  - name: 'node:20.7.0'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: [ 'run', 'build:$_BUILD_COMMAND', "--prod" ]

  - name: 'node:20.7.0'
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - 'rm -R node_modules'
      - 'rm -R src'
      - 'rm -R .angular'

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]

So I guess my question is, does anyone know of a way where I can not have 500+ MB of files in the service? The app has an extremely slow cold start and I believe the size may partially be the reason. Another thing, when I look at all of the files, excluding node modules they are only 8MB and with node_modules the entire project becomes bigger than 500MB so its my belief that even though I am ignoring the node_modules for some reason they are still being included in app engine.

Can you check this public issue tracker and confirm whether are you able to see files under data uploaded or not? Also can you share your directory structure?

Hello @RoopaM, These are most definitely not uploaded to a temporary location as App Engine is showing 500+MB as the service size. How do I find the directory structure in App Engine?

Hi Can you share your local directory structure? And to check if files not uploaded you can check under the Diagnose column click "Tools", then "Source", you get a screen that says: "Deployed Files". Under the directory structure, you can see non-deployed files.
